# How to insert a function into a cell with VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having problems inserting a functions into an Excel Sheet using VBA. I've never done this before. Is there a simple way?

I've tried using `Range(r,c).Formula = "=FUNCTION()"` and it works for cases like `"=SUM(C3:C10)"` but not for my code. I think is because of the string variable I have in between.

The code:

```
Sub populate()

Dim r As Long, r2 As Long, last_row As Long
Dim next_row As Long, current_len As Long, test_len As Long
Dim rng As String

With ActiveSheet

last_row = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For r = 2 To last_row
    next_row = r + 1

    If .Range("B" & next_row) > .Range("B" & r) Then
       current_len = .Range("B" & r)
       
       'create range
       For r2 = r + 1 To last_row
            test_len = .Range("B" & r2)
            If current_len >= test_len Then
                rng = "C" & r + 1 & ":" & "C" & r2 - 1
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    
        .Range("C" & r) = "subtotal(9;" & rng & ")" '<-------
    End If
    
Next

End With
End Sub
```

Comment: try .Range("C" & r).Formula = "=subtotal(9;" & rng & ")" '<-------

Comment: When using VBA and `Formula` to insert a formula, you need to use the "US" form - ie. comma as list separator, and not your local `;`.  If you want to use your local list separator use the `FormulaLocal` property instead.

Comment: Great stuff @Tim Williams

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a) You need to specify the formula using the comma as separator.
b) You need to put the `=`-sign in front of the formula (as you do in Excel)
c) You should write the formula into the property `Formula` of the cell.

```
.Range("C" & r).Formula = "=subtotal(9," & rng & ")"
```

Comment: The problem was the `;` I changed it to the coma `,` and it worked. Thanks @FunThomas